# how to lock Linux framebuffer temporary in c

Tags: c, linux, locking, mutex, framebuffer

I need to lock the Linux framebuffer in C for capture raw data and then release to continue. Similarly as is done in SDL when you lock/unlock surfaces for accessing. I´m not using SDL or OPENGL.

I´ve used mmap ( as it can trigger lock for the framebuffer ) but this code is for an small embedded device and mmap adds a cpu overhead (probably unnoticeable in bigger machines).

For what i´ve found around searching the web (please correct me if I am wrong ) mmap uses mutexes, data structures that work as thread semaphores to get the framebuffer lock.

What I´m looking for is the way to propperly set a framebuffer mutex lock manually and then unlock in C.

thanks in advance.